# Wireshark in promisc mode, Not capturing all packets from other devices

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

Im using wireshark on windows with an alfa network adapter, with promiscuous mode enabled. However, I am not seeing traffic from other devices on my network. See the screenshot of the capture I have attached. As you can see, I am filtering out my own computers traffic. Im on a WiFi network, and have tried everything. Any advice is greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: promiscuous mode has to be activated on the router/WIFI spot, not your machine's NIC.

Comment: Is this on Wi-Fi? What wireless security mode is in use in the target network? What are the Wi-Fi capabilities of the sniffer, the target AP, and the target client?

Answer (score 1):

Promiscuous mode on the network card means to pass all received network traffic up to applications (normally, traffic that isn't addressed to it it just discarded by the card). Today's networks are built on switches, and those forward to a network segment (one cable connected to a single network card, in typical setups) only the traffic of interest there (matching the addresses present in that segment). The card never gets traffic between other devices.

Comment: Wi-Fi is a radio signal and it can't be filtered out, it's either on the air or not, the switch it's for a physical device (cable).

Answer (score 0):

"Promiscuous Mode" in Wi-Fi terms (802.11) it's called "monitor mode" and this needs to be changed manually to the adapter from "Managed" to "Monitor", (This depends if the chipset allows it - Not all Wi-Fi adapters allow it) not with Wireshark.

Perhaps you would like to [read the instructions from wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Monitor_mode)

In which you'll find this on the "Monitor Mode" section:

> Monitor mode is not supported by WinPcap, and thus not by Wireshark or TShark, on Windows.

And then:

> You might have to perform operating-system-dependent and adapter-type-dependent operations to enable monitor mode, described below in the "Turning on monitor mode" section.

And after that under "Promiscuous mode" section:

> On Windows, putting 802.11 adapters into promiscuous mode is usually crippled, see the Windows section below.